# join tables time difference of 10 minutes [datetime2](7) NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join the values of 2 tables date for specific minutes . say data join for same date but hours can be + or - 10 minutes in difference.

```
select * from table1 inner join table2 where table1.starttime = table2.starttime
```

Here, I have an wait time of 10 minutes and the values has to be shown in case of difference is + or - 10 minutes

Comment: share some sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
select *
from table1 t1 inner join 
     table2 t2
     on t1.starttime >= dateadd(minute, -10, t2.starttime) or
        t1.starttime <= dateadd(minute, 10, t2.starttime);
```

This doesn't check for the same day.  If that is also desirable:

```
select *
from table1 t1 inner join 
     table2 t2
     on ( t1.starttime >= dateadd(minute, -10, t2.starttime) or
          t1.starttime <= dateadd(minute, 10, t2.starttime)
        ) and
        convert(date, t1.starttime) = convert(date, t2.starttime);
```

Comment: Super ! Thanks.. can you let me know why do you want to convert at the last ?

Comment: @Raj . . . So only the date component is compared.